# How to get values from an Object that have more objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a global variable `var room = {}` when i create a rooms it will go there and i will have the object like this

```
{
  '4bea542f-147c-4763-ab1c-bb6c40b1392e': {
    private: false,
    users: {
      btrJ7946MkjFSz_zAAAA: [Object],
      'qe_1igD7Q-RbDWc1AAAC': [Object]
    },
    gameS: false,
    nextUser: 'btrJ7946MkjFSz_zAAAA',
    timer: null,
    round: 0,
    winner: false,
    alreadyGuess: [],
    timerStartedAt: 0,
    settings: { gameStarted: false, time: null }
  },
  'e6ea6785-e522-4b8c-aeb8-b2551e89c895': {
    private: false,
    users: {
      'n5BODsuqAWb5Y-WAAAAD': [Object],
      paf4cWgX08Qi_8m5AAAE: [Object]
    },
    gameS: false,
    nextUser: 'n5BODsuqAWb5Y-WAAAAD',
    timer: null,
    round: 0,
    winner: false,
    alreadyGuess: [],
    timerStartedAt: 0,
    settings: { gameStarted: false, time: null }
  }
}
```

How can i access these objects with different names like '4bea542f-147c-4763-ab1c-bb6c40b1392e' and maybe get the ones with values private = false

Comment: [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

Comment: it should be Object.Keys(room)

Comment: `Object.values(room).filter(e => e.private === false)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you want to accomplish, striclty speaking to your question `Object.values()` is probably the easiest, but it won't keep the key, which you might be interested in keeping.

to get the keys, use `keys`

```js
var publicRoomsIds = Object.keys(rooms).filter(function (key) {
  var room = rooms[key];
  return (room.private === false);
});
```

to get the values (without keys) use `values`

```js
var publicRooms = Object.values(rooms).filter(function (room) {
  return (room.private === false);
});
```

```js
var rooms = {
  "4bea542f-147c-4763-ab1c-bb6c40b1392e": {
    private: false,
  },
  "e6ea6785-e522-4b8c-aeb8-b2551e89c895": {
    private: true,
  },
  "e6ea6785-3321-4b8c-aeb8-b2551e89c895": {
    private: false,
  },
  "e6ea6785-7663-4b8c-aeb8-b2551e89c895": {
    private: true,
  },
};

var publicRoomsIds = Object.keys(rooms).filter(function (key) {
  var room = rooms[key];
  return (room.private === false);
});

var publicRooms = Object.values(rooms).filter(function (room) {
  return (room.private === false);
});

console.log(publicRoomsIds);
console.log(publicRooms);
```

Comment: Just use `Object.entries()` if you need both the keys and values.

Comment: @VLAZ, I find `Object.entries` is a better replacement instead of using `map` on `Object.keys`. For `filter`ing it doesn's lend itself as-well.

Comment: `Object.entries(obj).filter(([, room]) => room.private === false)` or even `Object.entries(obj).filter(([, {private}]) => !private)`

Answer (score 0):

You can [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) over [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

```js
const o = { '4bea542f-147c-4763-ab1c-bb6c40b1392e': { private: false, users: { btrJ7946MkjFSz_zAAAA: [Object], 'qe_1igD7Q-RbDWc1AAAC': [Object] }, gameS: false, nextUser: 'btrJ7946MkjFSz_zAAAA', timer: null, round: 0, winner: false, alreadyGuess: [], timerStartedAt: 0, settings: { gameStarted: false, time: null } }, 'e6ea6785-e522-4b8c-aeb8-b2551e89c895': { private: false, users: { 'n5BODsuqAWb5Y-WAAAAD': [Object], paf4cWgX08Qi_8m5AAAE: [Object] }, gameS: false, nextUser: 'n5BODsuqAWb5Y-WAAAAD', timer: null, round: 0, winner: false, alreadyGuess: [], timerStartedAt: 0, settings: { gameStarted: false, time: null } } };
const res = Object.values(o).filter(x => !x.private);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

If you also want the key, you could use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/keys) or [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/entries).